# Using GitHub's REST API to update a release with a multi-line description

Tags: release, github-api

I am using JSON to update the description of a GitHub release with a list of the commits for that release.

The problem is that if the description has a newline the command fails with:

```
Stdout: {
Stdout:   "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
Stdout:   "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
Stdout: }
```

The only way I got it to work is to replace the newlines with a space:

```
def API_JSON = sprintf ('{"body": "%s"}', description.replace('\n',' '));
```

However, without the newlines the description is difficult to read. Is there a way to set the description for a GitHub release using the API/JSON and keep newlines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured out the answer, replace with a line break:

```
def API_JSON = sprintf ('{"body": "%s"}', description.replace('\n','<br />'));
```

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: Works well, however, the `<br />` [hardbreak](https://github.github.com/gfm/#hard-line-breaks) won't work within a markdown code block since (by design) it's intepreted as html code and thus displayed verbatim.  This can be worked around though by using the `<br />` linebreak within a preformatted tag `<pre>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\r\n` as well, only `\n` is not supported

```
curl -i -X 'POST' https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/releases/?access_token=:token' -d 
{
  "body": "My\r\nName"
}
```